# Get-ADObject -Identity doesn't find object when SAMAccountName is given in string - why?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-5.0

This is strange: Providing a variable with a `SAMAccountName`, `Get-ADObject`'s `Identity` parameter doesn't find the object whereas the `Filter` parameter does.

Why is that the case?

Here's my code:

```bsh
PS C:\Projects> Get-ADObject -Filter { SamAccountName -eq $FreeSam }

DistinguishedName                     Name         ObjectClass  ObjectGUID
-----------------                     ----         -----------  ----------
CN=TP1-sh123456,OU=TP1-Resources ...


PS C:\Projects> Get-ADObject -Identity $FreeSam
Cannot find an object with identity: 'TP1-sh123456' under: 'DC=tstglobal,DC=tst,DC=loc'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADObject -Identity $FreeSam
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (TP1-sh123456:ADObject) [Get-ADObject], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADObject
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [Get-ADObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adobject?view=win10-ps), it appears that the only valid inputs for the `Identity` parameter are

1. A distinguished Name
2. A GUID (ObjectGUID)

[Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) would work in this scenario:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $FreeSam
```

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize that the `Identity` parameter was implemented differently for each of the AD Cmdlets. Thanks a lot for enlightening me!